# kafka + too many open files between Kafka brokers or may between broker and clients

Tags: linux, file-descriptors, lsof, kafka

we are facing very major problem with our Apache Kafka servers
our Kafka servers are creased because "*Too many open files*"

we have production Kafka cluster with *7 machines* , while Kafka version is *0.1*

*OS version - RHEL 7.5*

we already increases twice the "*kafka_user_nofile_limit*" to *500000* , while the original value is *128000*

but again we are hit the high value and brokers are crashed

*additional we can see clearly that many lines as "Too many open files" are in Kafka logs*

we saw the following *Jira* case

https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/KAFKA-3317

but we not see what is the solution for this jira or what is the workaround for this major problem ?

**from jira**

```
 Bug
Status:OPEN
Priority: Major
Resolution:Unresolved
Affects Version/s:
0.9.0.0, 0.9.0.1
Fix Version/s:None
Component/s:None
Labels:None
Environment:CentOS release 6.5 (Final)
kafka_2.11-0.9.0.1
Flags:
Important
Description
there is much open files in my java app client which write msg to kafka broker, i used

<dependency>
<groupId>org.apache.kafka</groupId>
<artifactId>kafka-clients</artifactId>
<version>0.9.0.1</version>
</dependency>
new api to write msg. when i use

lsof -p 8780 | wc -l
19184
lsof -p 8780 | grep XmlIpcRegSvc | wc -l
4920
lsof -p 8780 | grep pipe | wc -l
9576
lsof -p 8780 | grep eventpoll | wc -l
4792
where 8780 is my java app pid.

java 37121 app *796u IPv6 960673997 0t0 TCP mad183:50213->mad180:XmlIpcRegSvc (ESTABLISHED)
there are many ESTABLISHED XmlIpcRegSvc , and seems not closed.
and It likes use ipv6 .
```

my configuration

```
 more /etc/security/limits.d/kafka.conf

# Licensed to the Apache Software Foundation (ASF) under one or more
# contributor license agreements.  See the NOTICE file distributed with
# this work for additional information regarding copyright ownership.
# The ASF licenses this file to You under the Apache License, Version 2.0
# (the "License"); you may not use this file except in compliance with
# the License.  You may obtain a copy of the License at
#
#     http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
#
# Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
# distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
# WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
# See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
# limitations under the License.

kafka   - nofile   500000
kafka   - nproc    65536
```

Comment: Did you also set soft & hard nofile limits in ````/etc/security/limits.conf````(If you're not using systemd to manage kafka) or ````LimitNOFILE=```` in your service file if you are using systemd?  Particularly in the systemd case, as I'm reasonably certain that Java can't control resource limits when being managed by systemd.

Comment: we are not using systemctl services , kafka is binary file  and kafka installed by HDP kit ( part of hortonworks )

Comment: How many files are you actually, well, tracking with kafka? If the number is greater than your limit then that's just the reality of the situation.

Comment: no , you miss the point , again see the jira bug , in my question , what I want is to know what is the solution for the jira Bug

Comment: I think you're misunderstanding, this is not an actual bug. This is a part of resource control. Which is also why there is no response on Jira to the issue. You either need to increase your limit( I think the max is 1048576; atleast on my system), or reduce the number of open files which probably means lowering retention time on topics.

Comment: why not a bug , this jira talk about "too many open files between Kafka brokers or may between broker and clients"  and maybe from some client version this cause the huge of open files

Comment: look on that also - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71284670/kafka-file-handle-leak-due-a-large-number-of-pipe-eventpoll-leak

Comment: If you are committed to the idea that you should not be seeing this volume of open files; you should report the bug to either the producer of the of the Kafka Client or Apache with detailed information; Stackexchange questions probably won't lead to you getting to getting the result you desire since its unlikely someone will debug and modify Kafka for you here.